# Changing the field on the MongoDatabase of a pojo class?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, nosql

I have a CSV file that I am reading into MongoDB using a POJO class like:

```java
public class Student {
    @JsonProperty("NAME")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private Integer id;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I want the fields in Mongo DB to be appeared like:

```json
{
  "NAME": "John",
  "ID": 4212
}
```

Instead they are like:

```json
{
  "name": "John",
  "id": 4212
}
```

All of them are lower case, instead of upper case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data MongoDB, you can use `@Field` to change the field name as follows:

```java
public class Student {
    @JsonProperty("NAME")
    @Field("NAME")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    @Field("ID")
    private Integer id;

    //getters and setters
}
```